# React refs callback return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

```
    <input
      type="text"
      ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
```

That's from the [React Docs on Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). I'm new to using refs and I'm curious about the use of the curly braces after the arrow notation inside the ref.  What is that callback returning exactly? Normally when I see curly braces after an arrow function, you need an explicit return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not returning anything. It's *assigning* the reference to `this.textInput`. You can omit the curly braces if you like, it won't make a difference. But the presence of the braces helps to signal that it's the side effect of the function that's important, not the return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
ref={(function (input) {this.textInput = input;}).bind(this);}
```